# Change border color for each data in amchart separately

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I saw there is an option to change the background color of each data entry in a pie chart but can not find a option to change the border color.

```
    memoryChartSeries.colors.list = [
      am4core.color('rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'), // blue
```

What I have found is `memoryChartSeries.slices.template.stroke` but I don't know if this can hold more than one color. I would expect something like:

```
    memoryChartSeries.border.colors.list = [
      am4core.color('rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'), // blue
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just set `pieSeries.slices.template.stroke`:

```
pieSeries.slices.template.stroke = am4core.color('rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)');
```

This will set the border color for all slices of your [pie chart](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/pie-chart/).

If you want to set the border color for each slice individually you might want to use an [adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/) for that:

```
pieSeries.slices.template.adapter.add("stroke", (value, target, key) => {
    // return what color you want here...
    return value;
});
```

Comment: Hmm, would be handier to have it in the same way as color... I will try the adapter because I want to give every slice its own background and border color

Comment: @muuvmuuv With which rules do you want to set the color of each slice?

Comment: In the adapter you can use `target.dataItem.dataContext` to set the data object for each slice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your custom color code array and set with the theme.

```
const colors = [
    am4core.color('#18020A'),
    am4core.color('#730154'),
    am4core.color('#E77624'),
    am4core.color('#7E5109'),
    am4core.color('#34495E'),
    am4core.color('#B3B6B7'),
    am4core.color('#232555'),
    am4core.color('#196F3D'),
    am4core.color('#6C3483'),           
]

const am4themes_myTheme = (target) => {
    if (target instanceof am4core.ColorSet) {       
        target.list =  themeModeChange(themeMode)
    }
}

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_myTheme);

series.columns.template.adapter.add("stroke", function (fill, target) {
    return chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index);
});
```

yo can change border color for each data in amchart separately.